# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost')

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I'm new at PHP Laravel. When I run in my terminal `php artisan serve` it shows me an error.
[image]

Also I can't have access at phpMyAdmin:[image]

As far I can understand, I can't have access to the database, even when I run `php artisan migrate` it shows the same error.

Comment: Ensure your database connection credentials in your `.env` file are correct, that the `user/password` combination exists and has access to your database and that your database service is running.

Comment: @basha04 if he is using the `root` user, permissions will not be a problem :-D

Comment: make sure you have DB_USERNAME="root" and DB_PASSWORD="" after that run "php artisan config:cache" and try again

Comment: how are you serving your database? are you using docker, valet, homestead or something else like xaamp or waamp?   Mysql needs to be running.

Comment: @Cameron , Im serving on xampp, I have access on phpMyAdmin, set the password there but still saying: ``` PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")```

Comment: The env: ```DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=prova1test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=passwordone23456```

Answer (score 1):

You should reset password in cmd by these commands

1. Open the bash shell and connect to the server as root user:

   mysql -u root -h localhost -p
2. Run ALERT mysql command:

   ALTER USER 'userName'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'New-Password-Here';
3. Finally type SQL command to reload the grant tables in the mysql database:

   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

more [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-change-user-password/)

Comment: Ehsan Ahmadi Kian, as soon as type the command ```mysql -u root -h localhost-p``` it asks for a password which I don't remember it.

Comment: you need to get your root password. for mysql. here are options for getting or resetting it   https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/xampp-mysql-password/      its telling you access denied. So the credentials you are using are wrong.  Try resetting your root password and entering the proper credentials in .env (be sure to clear config cache after changing those values) and you will need to re run artisan serve each time you change them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in .env file you set empty password for database access.Set database credentials properly in .env file and try again.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE= // your database name
DB_USERNAME= //root or your database user
DB_PASSWORD= // database password
```